# Cannot connect to url in C# with 401 unauthorized error

Tags: c#, url, webclient, http-status-code-401

I'm looking to get the content of a page from

```
http://12.18.60.199:81
```

I'm using my corporate network and if I use internet explorer, it prompts for username and password, I type that in and I get the content of the page. I need to do this in C#, but have no luck for the past few hours:

```
Uri requestUri = null;
Uri.TryCreate("http://12.18.60.199:81", UriKind.Absolute, out requestUri);

NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(@"username", @"password", "domain");
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(requestUri, "Basic", nc); //also tried "Anonymous", "Basic", "Digest",  "Dpa", 
                                 //"External", "Kerberos", "Msn", "Negotiate", "Ntlm", "Sicily" 

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Credentials = cache;
   using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://12.18.60.199:81"))
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
      //stuff
   }
}
```

Keep getting 401 unauthorized, invalid credentials, help!

If I substitute the above address with http://google.com, it'll work, so the code works... username and password have been tested to work in broswer

Comment: Do you run through a proxy server?

Comment: Sure the server uses basic authentication?  Try digest.

Comment: I'm not very good with these things, I do believe i'm using my corporate's proxy server when connecting to the internet since certain sites are blocked.

Comment: For the hell of it, I tried "Anonymous", "Basic", "Digest",  "Dpa", "External", "Kerberos", "Msn", "Negotiate", "Ntlm", "Sicily" same 401 error

Comment: I can't connect to it either... :)

Comment: It's an internal site. Works fine on my browser, but not in c#? why? :(

Comment: Any characters in the password that need to be escaped?

Comment: Good suggestion Rufus, but no the password is just plain text a-z

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting through a proxy server try adding in your proxy and pass the credentials. For example:

```
// Prepare web request...
HttpWebRequest myRequest =
   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.test.com");
// proxy details
myRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://10.0.0.1", true);
myRequest.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "password", "domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, and found workaround to add Authorization request header. I've used fiddler to get that base64. Never found proper solution, as you all know temp solutions are long-lasting in out world :)

```
service.Url = "http://127.0.0.1/";
service.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic dW8sX3NvYXB6SjRma2pzdXZqNDg5ZA==");            
service.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Comment: Hi j.v, this seems interesting, can you please paste the complete code example?

Comment: That is pretty much it. I use it for different purpose, for the web service authorization. It's just hint for you. Good luck